# getAttribute is not a function - can't iterate loop for every element

Tags: javascript

I know there is many similar questions but I don't know why it doesn't work to me

I have collection

```
cars = document.gelementsByClassName('car');
for (i in cars){
               let attr = cars[i].getAttribute('segment');
               }
```

And its going down with messege "getAttribute is not a function"
and loop is not go to end.
I tried use try-catch but it doesn't word
loop still not go to end
Even it is really error i would like to ignore this error and go to end.

Comment: what is supposed to be `gelementsByClassName`?

Comment: I'm more surprised you don't get an error earlier, since `gelementsByClassName` isn't a function. Typo in your example code?

Comment: I wrote it by hand its only small missing

Comment: Does any code in the page tamper with prototypes? Plus, try putting a `console.log(i)` before the erroneous line, so you'll see what property it has problem with (and what's its value).

Comment: I do that. Log show some values but loop don't go to end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `document.getElementsByClassName('car')` instead.

Also, to iterate through the `NodeList` using a [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement)  loop, you have to use [spread syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
var cars = [...document.getElementsByClassName('car')];
for (i in cars) {
  let attr = cars[i].getAttribute('segment');
  console.log(attr);
}
```

```html
<div class="car" segment="1"></div>
<div class="car" segment="2"></div>
<div class="car" segment="3"></div>
```

Comment: Um, actually, it's [not too good to use `for..in` even with spead here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-for-array-iteration-a-bad-idea); instead of the spread, you could just do `for..of` (it also works on Iterables)

Comment: Console log Show null